# How to log read only Java code in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

How can I add logging to read only code in IntelliJ?

Sometimes I need to know the value of variables in a external package without using a breakpoint. Is there a way (and if yes HOW ?) to add a watch that records the value to a log window/file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a breakpoint that will only log without suspending the execution.

[image: logging breakpint]

[Refer to the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lott , This is a real lifesaver for me !!